# Servicestack Multitenancy dynamic plugins

Tags: servicestack

We are moving from an on premise-like application to a multi tenant cloud application.

for my web application we made a very simple interface based on IPlugin, to create a plugin architecture. (customers can have/install different plugins)

```
public interface IWebPlugin : IPlugin
{
    string ContentBaseUrl { set; get; }
}
```

We have some plugins that would normally be loaded in on startup. Now i'm migrating the code to load at the beginning of a request (the Register function is called on request start), and scope everything inside this request. 
It's not ideal but it would bring the least impact on the plugin system for now.

I could scope the Container by making an AppHost child container which would stick to the request:

```
    Container IHasContainer.Container
    {
        get
        {
            if (HasStarted)
                return ChildContainer;
            return base.Container;

        } 
    }
    public Container ChildContainer
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Items.GetOrAdd<Container>("ChildContainer", c => Container.CreateChildContainer()); }
    }
```

### problem case

Now im trying to make plugins work that actually add API services.

```
   appHost.Routes.Add<GetTranslations>("/Localizations/translations", ApplyTo.Get);
```

But this service is unreachable (and not visible in metadata). How do i make it reachable?

I see you execute the following in ServiceController AfterInit. Re-executing this still wouldnt make it work.

```
    //Copied from servicestack repo
    public void AfterInit()
    {
        //Register any routes configured on Metadata.Routes
        foreach (var restPath in appHost.RestPaths)
        {
            RegisterRestPath(restPath);

            //Auto add Route Attributes so they're available in T.ToUrl() extension methods
            restPath.RequestType
                .AddAttributes(new RouteAttribute(restPath.Path, restPath.AllowedVerbs)
                {
                    Priority = restPath.Priority,
                    Summary = restPath.Summary,
                    Notes = restPath.Notes,
                });
        }

        //Sync the RestPaths collections
        appHost.RestPaths.Clear();
        appHost.RestPaths.AddRange(RestPathMap.Values.SelectMany(x => x));

        appHost.Metadata.AfterInit();
    }
```

### solution directions

Is there a way i could override the route finding? like extending `RestHandler.FindMatchingRestPath(httpMethod, pathInfo, out contentType);`

Or could i restart the path compilation/caching? (would be enough for now that the service would be reachable tenant wide )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer seems to be, no. The framework wasn't build to be a run-time plugable system.

You will have to make this architecture yourself on top of ServiceStack.

## Routing solution

To make it route to these run-time loaded services/routes it is needed to make your own implementation.

The ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory checks if a route exist (one that is registered on init). so here is where you will have to start extending. The method `GetHandlerForPathInfo` checks if it can find the (service)route and otherwise return a NotFoundHandler or StaticFileHandler.

My solution consists of the following code:

```
 string contentType;
 var restPath = RestHandler.FindMatchingRestPath(httpMethod, pathInfo, out contentType);
 //Added part
 if (restPath == null)
     restPath = AppHost.Instance.FindPluginServiceForRoute(httpMethod, pathInfo);
//End added part
 if (restPath != null)
     return new RestHandler { RestPath = restPath, RequestName = restPath.RequestType.GetOperationName(), ResponseContentType = contentType };
```

technically speaking `IAppHost.IServiceRoutes` should be the one doing the routing. Probably in the future this will be extensible.

### Resolving services

The second problem is resolving the services. After the route has been found and the right Message/Dto Type has been resolved. The `IAppHost.ServiceController` will attempt to find the right service and make it execute the message.

This class also has init functions which are called on startup to reflect all the services in servicestack. I didn't found a work around yet, but ill by working on it to make it possible in ServiceStack coming weeks.

Current version on nuget its not possible to make it work. I added some extensibility in servicestack to make it +- possible.

## Ioc Solution out of the box

For ioc ServiceStack.Funq gives us a solution. Funq allows making child containers where you can register your ioc on. On resolve a child container will, if it can't resolve the interface, ask its parent to resolve it.

`Container.CreateChildContainer()`

Answer (score 1):

All configuration in ServiceStack should be contained within `AppHost.Configure()` and remain immutable thereafter. It's not ThreadSafe to modify ServiceStack's Static Configuration at runtime like trying to modify registered routes or Service Metadata which needs to be registered once at StartUp in `AppHost.Configure()`.

It looks as though you'll need to re-architect your solution so all Routes are registered on Startup. If it helps [Plugins](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins) can implement `IPreInitPlugin` and `IPostInitPlugin` interfaces to execute custom logic before and after Plugins are registered. They can also register a `appHost.AfterInitCallbacks` to register custom logic after ServiceStack's AppHost has been initialized.

Not sure if it's applicable but at runtime you can "hi-jack Requests" in ServiceStack by registering a [RawHttpHandler or a PreRequestFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations), e.g:

```
appHost.RawHttpHandlers.Add(httpReq =>
    MyShouldHandleThisRoute(httpReq.PathInfo)
        ?  new CustomActionHandler((req, res) => {
               //Handle Route
           });
        : null);
```

Comment: Yea i already knew this part, but i actually wanted/doing to the opposite (of what you suggest), to create a runtime pluggable application. But i see i'll have to hook in parts myself if i want this. I might duplicate the HttpHandlerFactory and adjust it the way i want. Too bad its all static so i there are no overwrite possibilities.

Comment: would it be possible to make the HttpHandlerFactory unstatic and overrideable?

Comment: @joelharkes not until next release, I'd want a full release cycle to make sure any disruption doesn't cause any issues. You can copy + paste impl in the meantime.